# send an email in Laravel on a create function

Tags: laravel

send an email in Laravel on a create function but not able to do
this is my store function

```
 public function store()
    {
        $input = $request->all();
        $user = \AUTH::guard()->user();
        $input['created_by'] = $user->id;
        \Log::info('$input'.json_encode([$input]));

        $bulkLabSample = $this->bulkLabSampleRepository->create($input);

        Flash::success(__('messages.saved', ['model' => __('models/bulkLabSamples.singular')]));

        return redirect(route('bulkLabSamples.index'));
    }
```

Comment: Have you read the documentation on [mailables](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/mail)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// use this
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;

// send mail via mail
Mail::send('your-view-blade', ['extraInfo' => $extraInfo], function ($message) {
     $message->to('email@email.com');
      $message->subject('your subject here');
});

By extraInfo you can pass values to the mail template as you want.






// for your code

public function store()
    {
        $input = $request->all();
        $user = \AUTH::guard()->user();
        $input['created_by'] = $user->id;
        \Log::info('$input'.json_encode([$input]));

        $bulkLabSample = $this->bulkLabSampleRepository->create($input);

        Mail::send('your-view-blade', ['extraInfo' => $extraInfo], function ($message) {
            $message->to('email@email.com');
            $message->subject('your subject here');
        });

        Flash::success(__('messages.saved', ['model' => __('models/bulkLabSamples.singular')]));

        return redirect(route('bulkLabSamples.index'));
    }
```

Comment: In .env file, you will see these variables. Just fill this information with your own. For testing, you can create an account in **mailtrap.io**, select Laravel, and fill in your own info.

`MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME="user name"
MAIL_PASSWORD="your password from mail sender"
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS="admin@admin.com"
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"`